# jQuery build a custom querystring formating not right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a custom query string that has to look like this:

```
?filter[pv_number]=12&filter[location_of_facts]=West
```

But when I log it, it looks like this:

```
?filter%5Bpv_number%5D=12&filter%5Blocation_of_facts%5D=West
```

My jquery

```
let pv_number = $( "input[name=pv_number]" ).val();
let location = $( "input[name=location_of_facts]" ).val();

let params = {'filter[pv_number]':pv_number, 'filter[location_of_facts]':location};
let queryString = jQuery.param(params);

console.log(queryString);
```

### EDIT

When I do a redirect:

```
window.location.href = queryString;
```

I go to this page:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/?filter%5Bpv_number%5D=651&filter%5Blocation_of_facts%5D=West

Instead of this page: (my goal)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?filter[pv_number]=651&filter[location_of_facts]=West
```

### EDIT 2 Full jquery

```
$('#filterSearch').on('click', function(e) {
    let pv_number = $("input[name=pv_number]").val();
    let location = $("input[name=location_of_facts]").val();

    //filter[id]=1
    let params = {'filter[pv_number]':pv_number, 'filter[location_of_facts]':location};
    let queryString = jQuery.param(params);

    window.location.href = + '?' + queryString ;
});
```

This redirects to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?filter%5Bpv_number%5D=651&filter%5Blocation_of_facts%5D=West
```

I want to go to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?filter[pv_number]=651&filter[location_of_facts]=West
```

Comment: That's normal behaviour. The value has been URL encoded. This isn't an issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But I need to to a redirect to an url that looks like my example with actual "[]" brackets

Comment: You can do that, the `%5D` etc. values are simply encoded. They will be decoded when received on the server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Okay I will try it out

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It doesn't work :( check out my edited post

Comment: Ok, so the important part of the code is how you're reading the values from the URL. Could you please edit the question to include that. Also note that your question still doesn't actually explain what the issue is, it would be helpful if you included that too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't know how I can explain it better but I need to "surf" to the url I gave as (my goal) if i type that in my browser it works and I am trying to replicate that with jquery but the values come from text boxes I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

This is not a issue. Anyway, you can use decodeURI(queryString) for log purposes

Answer (score 0):

mark the following two lines

`// let params = {'filter[pv_number]':pv_number, 'filter[location_of_facts]':location};
// let queryString = jQuery.param(params);`

Try this

```
let queryString = `filter[pv_number]=${pv_number}&filter[location_of_facts]=${location_}`;
```

location is a reserved keyword, so I changed to location_